# SQL server XML type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

I have an XML type column in SQL server:

```
<LogMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="LogMessageBusinessServiceRequest">
  <Application>Services.Business.myapp</Application>
  <Time>2013-05-30T15:01:38.932Z</Time>
  <Level>Info</Level>
  <Message>MultiQuery Biz Request</Message>
  <MachineName>Machine1</MachineName>
  <ThreadId>16084</ThreadId>
  <Callsite>BLAH</Callsite>
  <CreatedBy>Machine1\svc_biz_myapp</CreatedBy>
  <Context>
    <myappExtraInfo xmlns="http://services.somedomain.com/myapp/logging/extraInfo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <CallType>MultiProcessQuery</CallType>
      <RequestId>r163505508498822282742</RequestId>
      <FirmId>160</FirmId>
      <PMFirmId>203</PMFirmId>
      <SubscriptionId>0</SubscriptionId>
      <Token />
      <LastClientSvcTimeMs>0</LastClientSvcTimeMs>
      <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
      <ResultCodeDescription>OK</ResultCodeDescription>
      <ElapsedTimeTotalMs>110</ElapsedTimeTotalMs>
      <ElapsedTimeMtMs>110</ElapsedTimeMtMs>
      <ElapsedTimeDacMs>109</ElapsedTimeDacMs>
      <ElapsedTimePMSSMs>-1</ElapsedTimePMSSMs>
    </myappExtraInfo>
  </Context>
```

I want to get the FirmID from there. But I am not able with the following section of my select statement:

```
select
[Body].value('(/LogMessage/Context/myappExtraInfo/FirmId)[1]', 'varchar(max)') FirmID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

- Shiyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you need to **respect** the XML namespace that's defined on your `<myappExtraInfo>` node (and thus applies to all subnodes, too):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES(1, 
'<LogMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="LogMessageBusinessServiceRequest">
  <Application>Services.Business.myapp</Application>
  <Time>2013-05-30T15:01:38.932Z</Time>
  <Level>Info</Level>
  <Message>MultiQuery Biz Request</Message>
  <MachineName>Machine1</MachineName>
  <ThreadId>16084</ThreadId>
  <Callsite>BLAH</Callsite>
  <CreatedBy>Machine1\svc_biz_myapp</CreatedBy>
  <Context>
    <myappExtraInfo xmlns="http://services.somedomain.com/myapp/logging/extraInfo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <CallType>MultiProcessQuery</CallType>
      <RequestId>r163505508498822282742</RequestId>
      <FirmId>160</FirmId>
      <PMFirmId>203</PMFirmId>
      <SubscriptionId>0</SubscriptionId>
      <Token />
      <LastClientSvcTimeMs>0</LastClientSvcTimeMs>
      <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
      <ResultCodeDescription>OK</ResultCodeDescription>
      <ElapsedTimeTotalMs>110</ElapsedTimeTotalMs>
      <ElapsedTimeMtMs>110</ElapsedTimeMtMs>
      <ElapsedTimeDacMs>109</ElapsedTimeDacMs>
      <ElapsedTimePMSSMs>-1</ElapsedTimePMSSMs>
    </myappExtraInfo>
  </Context>
 </LogMessage>')


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://services.somedomain.com/myapp/logging/extraInfo' AS ns)
SELECT
    XmlContent.value('(/LogMessage/Context/ns:myappExtraInfo/ns:FirmId)[1]', 'int')
FROM @Test
WHERE ID = 1
```

This returns the value `160` to me.